# code to cancel installation procedure in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

i have a form to take a code and validate it at the time of installation of Windows application.

1. if i want to close the form , a message box should appear and ask to exit installation.

i had used the following code in the form

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "123")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("U r registered user now !!","", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                this.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }

    private void checkclose(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit installation !!", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
          //Code to exit installation 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide valid code to continue installation !!");
            e.Cancel = true;

        }

    }
```

i want the code to exit installation.
please someone provide it.

Comment: why can't you just close the window when user cancel's the incstallation by using `this.Close()`.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi this.close closes the form containing textbox and the installation is continued. i want when i close the form , the installation automatically gets rollbacked or exit .

Comment: how are you instantiating the installation window? is it seperate window?

Comment: yes,its a seperate window ..

Comment: do u knw how to use User interface ??

Comment: you can kill the installation window by killing its process if you know the name, check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] ProcessList = Process.GetProcessesByName("Your Setup FileName");
foreach (Process process in ProcessList)
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: @Divyanshu: no it's in `C#`

Comment: @Divyanshu: you need to import `System.Diagnostics;` namespace using this statement -->`using System.Diagnostics;` check my edited answer.

Comment: thnkx for ur effort.. do u knw how to take value in textbox in user interface dialogs in setup and deployment

Comment: @Divyanshu: sorry i don't have an idea.btw was your problem solved?

Comment: @Divyanshu: what happens when you run the above code?are you getting any exception?

Comment: code is correct but the installation window doesnt close when i closed the form..

Comment: @Divyanshu: do you know the exact name of the installation process name, if not please goto task manager and identify the name of the process.